# Make repeating numbers 0 and putting them at the beginning of array

Tags: java

I am new to programming and I have made a program to make all repeating numbers in an array 0 and put those all 0s in left side:

```
import java.util.*;
class ArrayWork
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arr[],n,i,j,nr[]= new int[5];
        System.out.println("Enter the value for n: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        if(n>25)
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        else
        {
            arr = new int[n]; 
            System.out.println("Enter the array elements: ");
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            int count =0;
            for( i=0; i< arr.length-1;i++)
            { for (j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++)
                {if(arr[i]==arr[j])
                   nr[i]=arr[i];
                    System.out.println(nr[i]);
                }}
            for(int v=0;v<n;v++){  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                if(arr[i]==nr[v])
                {
                    for(j=i-1;j>=0&&arr[j]>0;j--)
                    {
                        arr[j+1]=arr[j];
                    }
                    arr[j+1]=0;
                }
            }}

            System.out.println("The array is: ");
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Can I do anything to make this program smaller although the output is coming right and the program is ok
but I have made many loop,
Hope you know any better way?

INPUT:

```
10,20,20,4,4,6
```

OUTPUT:

```
0,0,0,0,10,6
```

Comment: It could be better/simpler and should be properly formatted. Also, just checking: What happens if the input is `1,2,2,2,3`?

Comment: The array is: 
0 0 0 1 3

Comment: Cool. It’s hard to tell due to formatting problems, especially indentation. Use an IDE and get it to reformat the code for you.

Comment: well, i have made it in bluej

Comment: Oh duplicate numbers are _removed_, not consolidated? Well crap, let me update my answer

Comment: @ChildhoodToons Do you want *all duplicate values* to be removed, or only *adjacent duplicates*? For example, should `7` be removed in the following sequence: `2, 7, 3, 4, 7, 5`?

Answer (score 2):

## Declaration

> ```java
> int arr[],n,i,j,nr[]= new int[5];
> ```

Consider to declare variables on separate lines. From *Code Complete, 2nd Edition, p761*:

> **Use only one data declaration per line**
>
> [...]
>
> It’s easier to modify declarations because each declaration is self-contained.
>
> [...]
>
> It’s easier to find specific variables because you can scan a single column rather than reading each line. It’s easier to find and fix syntax errors because the line number the compiler gives you has only one declaration >on it.

## Unused Variables

> ```java
> int count =0;
> ```

`count` gets declared and initialized but is never in use.. Unused variables should be removed.

## [Magic Number](https://refactoring.guru/replace-magic-number-with-symbolic-constant)

> Your code uses a number that has a certain meaning to it.

One magic number is hidden in the code.

> ```java
> if(n>25) {
> ```

You can create a new constant variable `MAX_SIZE`

> ```java
> if(n>MAX_SIZE) {
> ``
> ```

## Formatting

> ```java
> for( i=0; i< arr.length-1;i++)
> { for (j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++)
>     {if(arr[i]==arr[j])
>        nr[i]=arr[i];
>         System.out.println(nr[i]);
>     }}
> ```

The code has an inconsistent formatting. Some key words are on a new-line and some times on the same line of a `{`.

Additional the code is format in a more C-like style, which I respect but you should have a look into [Oracles Code Conventions for the Java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

## Reduce Code Complexity Via Methods

When we consider a [Code Smell Metrics](http://wiki.c2.com/?CodeSmellMetrics) and look at the code, we will find at least two points, that apply:

> - Methods with more than 20 lines of code
> - Methods with nesting more than 2 (?) levels deep
> - Any global or static variables

To reduce the complexity we can introduce some new methods. For example

> ```java
> for(i=0;i<n;i++)
> {
>     arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
> }
> ```

can be wrapped into a method `storeUserInput`.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear that you specifically need to be working with arrays or if you just need to be manipulating a set of numbers. If there's no such requirement, you could use an `ArrayList` and dynamically allocate your buffer instead. This also gives you some built-in ways to find and move entries around using the `List` interface. (Technically, if your input and output type is strictly an array, perhaps you still could still convert to an `ArrayList` to do your work then convert back.)

Other comments:

- I'm unsure if there's any particular reason to hard cap your buffer sizes but it can be avoided
- `Scanner` is an object that should be cleaned up (it doesn't matter much in this simple program but generally you should release resources when you no longer need them (consider if this was reading a file stream instead). You can either call `close()` on the object after you're done reading inputs or wrap the usage in a [try-with-resources block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)
- As always, more comments and clearer variable names are appreciated

Here's an example that prioritizes minimizing the number of loops in the code, this one has two loops and an inner loop (input, search, replace):

```
int listSize;
List<Integer> list;

try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.println("Enter the array size: ");
    listSize = scanner.nextInt();

    list = new ArrayList<>(listSize);
    System.out.println("Enter the array elements: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i) {
        list.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i) {
    int value = list.get(i);
    int lastIndex = list.lastIndexOf(value);
    if (lastIndex > i) {
        // there's another element of this value after this one
        for (int j = i; j <= lastIndex; ++j) {
            if (list.get(j) == value) {
                // repeated value to zero and move to the beginning of the list
                list.remove(j);
                list.add(0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("The array is: ");
for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
    System.out.print(list.get(i) + " ");
}
```

This example may not be the most efficient but it tries to make the most of built-in functions, and saves you the effort of managing an array directly. In general that would be my advice, see what already exists in standard libraries to do simple operations.

I think this could be reduced further to eliminate the inner loop and only have an input loop, possibly with a second loop afterwards. Constructs like `HashMap` could also be utilized to detect duplicates and go down to one input loop. I'll leave that as an exercise to someone else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Use hashmap, in first traversal, gather all values with their counts.
Initiate an arraylist, do second traversal, if count of that element is 1, append the element to list.
At the end, prepend as many number of zeros as the difference the length of list and input array.

Comment: i haven't have used hashmap before just heard but thanks i will try

Comment: HashMap won’t work. (I *think*) OP only wants *adjacent* dupes removed.

Answer (score 0):

I would do most of this in a single loop:

```
//if length of the input is < 2, just return it
int[] input = /* our input array with ANY numbers or amount of them  */
int j = input.length - 2;
int last = input[input.length - 1]; //the number after ours index-wise
//i is for search, j is for replacement
for (int i = input.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    int current = input[i]; //the number we're comparing
    if (current != last) { //if it's unique
        j--; //move the area we'll zero-fill over one
        continue; //next loop iteration, last is the same
    //below this point assumes the number is a duplicate
    } else if (i > 0) { //if i is 0, the j-loop will handle it
        //rather than search the array for the next number, we'll just shift here
        input[i] = input[i - 1]; //grab the proceeding number and fill it in
    }
    last = current; //update our comparison with the old number that was possibly replaced
}
for (; j >= 0; j--) {
    input[j] = 0; //zero out the area outside our unique numbers
}
```

There's certainly room for a little improvement, but for phone-typing I'm hoping I got the point across. Let me know if you've got any questions, like the funky j-loop for instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
final static int MAX_NUMBER = 500;
final static int MAX_SIZE = 25;
static int[] count = new int[MAX_NUMBER];
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the value for n: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    if(n > MAX_SIZE) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input: " + n);
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter the array elements: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        count[arr[i]]++;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < n ;i++) {
        if(count[arr[i]] == 1) {
            result.add(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The array is: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < n - result.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print("0 ");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(result.get(i) + " ");
    }
}
```

Here I tried to simplify your code. As you are new to programming I havent used a hashmap. Basically after reading the input array, in count array you store how many times they occur. Then you iterate the array, if the current element count is 1 you add it to the result list.